# here-api | no response on category

Tags: here-api

I am using the API (Geocoding and Search API) from here to get some geodata. So far everything is working perfectly except I do not get a response to a specific category: 400-4100-0226

Every other category is returning data, except this one. Here the request, that works with every other. I checked other locations as well.

[https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?apiKey=*"xxx"*&at=52,13&categories=400-4100-0226](https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?apiKey=*%22xxx%22*&at=52,13&categories=400-4100-0226)

Comment: The category you are looking at seems to be highway exits, I did search somewhere near a highway and it did return data: 
https://browse.search.hereapi.com/v1/browse?apiKey={{API_KEY}}&at=47.636988,-122.322661&categories=400-4100-0226

It just doesn't seem to have much data about Germany for some reason.

Comment: Thanks for the testing, you are right - on your location I get also results. But why I do not get any results in Europe? I get results for any other category I've tried so far. Google and OSM are getting results on highway exits for this location.